# Python-Repl issues with TRAMP Mode [windows->Linux]

Tags: python, tramp, ipython, repl

I have an issue when using python-mode remotely through tramp. I'm trying to use the repl and pass a test function
using `C-c C-c`, however this seems to create a local file at my own computer or remotely using a `c:` prefix instead of `usr/`

Alongside this the terminal that I create with run-python seems to create a bunch of gibberish (as can be visible below) although it does run. if I test it directly (not by sending `C-c C-c`)
I would appreciate any ideas in order to fix this.

```
Sent: def test():...
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘c:/Users//Local/Temp/tramp.12516UhC’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/plink:.net:/tmp/py12516iXz’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘c:/Users//Temp/tramp.12516hrI’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/plink::/tmp/py12516iXz’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/plink:.net:/tmp/py12516iXz’...
Tramp: Encoding remote file ‘/plink:.net:/tmp/py12516iXz’ with ‘base64 <%s’...done
Tramp: Decoding local file ‘c://Temp/tramp.12516u1O’ with ‘base64-decode-region’...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/plink:.net:/tmp/py12516iXz’...done
error in process filter: ansi-color-filter-apply: Args out of range: "[0;38;5;28;1mimport[0m [0;38;5;32;1mcodecs[0m,[0m [0;38;5;32;1mos[0m;[0m__pyfile[0m [0m=[0m [0mcodecs[0m.[0mopen[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m,[0m [0mencod
[79Ci[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mng[0m=[0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__code[0m [0m=[0m [0m__pyfile[0m.[0mread[0m()[0m.[0mencode[0m([0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__pyfile[0m.[0mc
[79Cl[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mose[0m();[0mos[0m.[0mremove[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m);[0mexec[0m([0;38;5;28mcompile[0m([0m__code[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'''c:/hom
[79Ce[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0;38;5;130m/_Recorder/test.py'''[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'exec'[0m));[69D[69C[0m[3A[69D[0m[J[0;38;5;28mIn [[0;38;5;10;1m1[0;38;5;28m]: [0;38;5;28;1mimport[0m [0;38;5;32;1mcodecs[0m,[0m [0;38;5;32;1mos[0m;[0m__pyfile[0m [0m=[0m [0mcodecs[0m.[0mopen[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m,[0m [0mencod
[79Ci[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mng[0m=[0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__code[0m [0m=[0m [0m__pyfile[0m.[0mread[0m()[0m.[0mencode[0m([0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__pyfile[0m.[0mc
[79Cl[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mose[0m();[0mos[0m.[0mremove[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m);[0mexec[0m([0;38;5;28mcompile[0m([0m__code[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'''c:/hom
[79Ce[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0;38;5;130m/_Recorder/test.py'''[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'exec'[0m));[69D[0m

[J[0m", 1551
error in process filter: Args out of range: "[0;38;5;28;1mimport[0m [0;38;5;32;1mcodecs[0m,[0m [0;38;5;32;1mos[0m;[0m__pyfile[0m [0m=[0m [0mcodecs[0m.[0mopen[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m,[0m [0mencod
[79Ci[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mng[0m=[0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__code[0m [0m=[0m [0m__pyfile[0m.[0mread[0m()[0m.[0mencode[0m([0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__pyfile[0m.[0mc
[79Cl[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mose[0m();[0mos[0m.[0mremove[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m);[0mexec[0m([0;38;5;28mcompile[0m([0m__code[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'''c:/hom
[79Ce[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0;38;5;130m/_Recorder/test.py'''[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'exec'[0m));[69D[69C[0m[3A[69D[0m[J[0;38;5;28mIn [[0;38;5;10;1m1[0;38;5;28m]: [0;38;5;28;1mimport[0m [0;38;5;32;1mcodecs[0m,[0m [0;38;5;32;1mos[0m;[0m__pyfile[0m [0m=[0m [0mcodecs[0m.[0mopen[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m,[0m [0mencod
[79Ci[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mng[0m=[0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__code[0m [0m=[0m [0m__pyfile[0m.[0mread[0m()[0m.[0mencode[0m([0;38;5;130m'''utf-8'''[0m);[0m__pyfile[0m.[0mc
[79Cl[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0mose[0m();[0mos[0m.[0mremove[0m([0;38;5;130m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m);[0mexec[0m([0;38;5;28mcompile[0m([0m__code[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'''c:/hom
[79Ce[0m

[0;38;5;28m   ...: [0;38;5;130m//test.py'''[0m,[0m [0;38;5;130m'exec'[0m));[69D[0m

[J[0m", 1551
error in process filter: ansi-color-filter-apply: Args out of range: "[0;31m---------------------------------------------------------------------------[0m
[0;31mFileNotFoundError[0m                         Traceback (most recent call last)
[0;32m<ipython-input-1-05c5f2e548bf>[0m in [0;36m<module>[0;34m()[0m
[0;32m----> 1[0;31m [0;32mimport[0m [0mcodecs[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mos[0m[0;34m;[0m[0m__pyfile[0m [0;34m=[0m [0mcodecs[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mopen[0m[0;34m([0m[0;34m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mencoding[0m[0;34m=[0m[0;34m'''utf-8'''[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m;[0m[0m__code[0m [0;34m=[0m [0m__pyfile[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mread[0m[0;34m([0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mencode[0m[0;34m([0m[0;34m'''utf-8'''[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m;[0m[0m__pyfile[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mclose[0m[0;34m([0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m;[0m[0mos[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mremove[0m[0;34m([0m[0;34m'''c:/tmp/py12516iXz'''[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m;[0m[0mexec[0m[0;34m([0m[0mcompile[0m[0;34m([0m[0m__code[0m[0;34m,[0m [0;34m'''c:/home//Cerberus_Recorder/test.py'''[0m[0;34m,[0m [0;34m'exec'[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m;[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0m
[0;32m/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py[0m in [0;36mopen[0;34m(filename, mode, encoding, errors, buffering)[0m
[1;32m    894[0m         [0;31m# Force opening of the file in binary mode[0m[0;34m[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    895[0m         [0mmode[0m [0;34m=[0m [0mmode[0m [0;34m+[0m [0;34m'b'[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0;32m--> 896[0;31m     [0mfile[0m [0;34m=[0m [0mbuiltins[0m[0;34m.[0m[0mopen[0m[0;34m([0m[0mfilename[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mmode[0m[0;34m,[0m [0mbuffering[0m[0;34m)[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[0m[1;32m    897[0m     [0;32mif[0m [0mencoding[0m [0;32mis[0m [0;32mNone[0m[0;34m:[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
[1;32m    898[0m         [0;32mreturn[0m [0mfile[0m[0;34m[0m[0m
```

I have also attempted using this defun:

```
(defun python-send-region (start end)
  "Send the region to the inferior Python process."

  (interactive "r")

  (let* ((loc_name)
     (f (if (file-remote-p default-directory)
        (let* ((con (tramp-dissect-file-name default-directory)))
          (setq loc_name (tramp-make-tramp-temp-file con))
          (concat "/"
              (tramp-file-name-method con) ":"
              (tramp-file-name-user con) "@"
              (tramp-file-name-host con) ":"
              loc_name
              ))
          (setq loc_name (make-temp-file "py"))))
     (command (format "emacs.eexecfile(%S)" loc_name))
     (orig-start (copy-marker start)))
    (save-excursion
      (let ((curbuf (current-buffer))
        (tempbuf (get-buffer-create "*python_temp*")))
    (set-buffer tempbuf)
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (insert-buffer-substring curbuf start end)
    (python-mode)
    (when (save-excursion 
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (/= 0 (current-indentation)))
      (python-shift-left (point-min) (point-max)))
    (write-region nil nil f nil 'nomsg))

    (python-send-command command)
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer (python-proc))
      ;; Tell compile.el to redirect error locations in file `f' to
      ;; positions past marker `orig-start'.  It has to be done *after*
      ;; `python-send-command''s call to `compilation-forget-errors'.
      (compilation-fake-loc orig-start f)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended solving this by directly sending to the *Python* buffer. Hope it helps

```
(setq tiqsi-python-buffer "*Python*")

(defun send-py-line ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((py-temp (thing-at-point 'line t)))
    (comint-send-string tiqsi-python-buffer py-temp)))

(defun send-py-region(begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (comint-send-string tiqsi-python-buffer
              (buffer-substring-no-properties begin end))
  (comint-send-string tiqsi-python-buffer "\n"))
```